# Connection to Docker SQL Server container does not work Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, docker, entity-framework-core

Having issues with connecting to SQL Server in Docker container.

I'm using this to setup the container:

```
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=********" -e "MSSQL_PID=Evaluation" -p 1433:1433  --name sqlserver --hostname sqlserver -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-preview-ubuntu-22.04
```

This is my connection string:

```
"Server=localhost,1433;Database=TemplateDb;User Id=sa;Password=********;Integrated Security=false;TrustServerCertificate=true"
```

I'm getting this exception:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server: Could not open a connection to SQL Server)'

Regular connection via Management Studio or Azure Data Studio to the container works fine. Database is created. I tried to restart container, I checked firewall settings, I even tried to connect via docker exec - works. In docker -ps is container running.

Comment: So from where to where are you connecting? One container that runs the db and another that is the client?

Comment: So where is the `SqlException` getting thrown from, an application on the Docker host or an application in a Docker container? From a networking perspective Docker containers are their own little VM, so `127.0.0.1`, `::1` and `localhost` all refer to the container itself. If you want to connect between containers they should be in a composition together and can reference each other by DNS/container name and their `expose` port. If the containers are standalone or in seperate compositions then they need to connect through `host.docker.internal` on their `publish` ports.

Comment: To better understand the issue, can you provide more details?
- **Environment**: Are you running Docker natively or through Docker Desktop (e.g., on macOS or Windows)?
- **Docker Version**: What's your Docker version? (`docker --version`)
- **EF Core Version**: Which Entity Framework Core version are you using?
- **Container Logs**: Can you share the logs from the SQL Server Docker container? (`docker logs sqlserver`)

Comment: - **Application Context**: Is your application (trying to connect to SQL) inside another Docker container or on the host machine?
- **Error Details**: Any additional details in the exception stack trace when you get the connection error?
- **Security**: Are there any firewalls or security software that could be blocking the connection?

Comment: "Regular connection via Management Studio or Azure Data Studio to the container works fine" and what are the settings that work?

Comment: SqlException is thrown on ASP.NET application which is trying to connect to docker container running MSSQL server. When connecting via Management Studio I entered localhost, 1433 as server name and same credentials as above.

Comment: The ASP.NET app is in container as well. Regarding firewall, I checked docker in general in firewall and its enabled. No security software that could block the connection is on the device.

Comment: It seems to be issue with the connection between containers, not the code or connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Dont Have enough rep to upvote on @Amit Mohanty's response. But that worked for me and saved me a headache.

My Connection string for running an sql server 2022 and connecting to it in entityframeworkcore 7.0.13, looked like this:

"Server=MyDockerContainerName,1433;Database=bookify;User Id=sa;Password=Password123!;Encrypt=false;TrustServerCertificate=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"

dont use localhost use the docker container name.

Answer (score -1):

You've used `Server=localhost,1433`, which would refer to the local machine, not the Docker container. To connect to the SQL Server running in the Docker container, you should use the container name (or IP address) as the server name in your connection string. In your case, you've named the container `sqlserver`, so your connection string should look like this:

```
"Server=sqlserver,1433;Database=TemplateDb;User Id=sa;Password=********;Integrated Security=false;TrustServerCertificate=true"
```

Comment: I did try both Server=localhost,1433 and Server=sqlserver,1433. None of them worked, I also tried to remove the Integraded Security and that didn't work as well.

Comment: Check the logs of your SQL Server container to see if there are any errors reported during startup or related to connection attempts by running this command: `docker logs sqlserver`

Comment: They seem pretty clean, there some older stuff which is not relevant anymore I think